# Passing reference to activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple multiplayer game on android. I have NetworkManager class which opens connection to the server and provides methods like *send* and *receive*.

```
public class NetworkManager {

    private Socket socket;

    public NetworkManager() throws IOException
    {
        socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

        ...

    }

    public void send(String msg) throws IOException { ... }

}
```

In one activity I connect to the server by creating new instance of NetworkManager. Then, I have to use that instance in several other activities. Is it possible to pass reference to it when starting new activity?

Comment: consider a service and binding your service from your activity: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and you should not do it anyway. Use a service to do the background work: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html - or at least an AsyncTask, but for your use case a service should be a better option.

You can only pass primitive or Parcelable types from one Activity to another.